# Java Swing Focus Border too small

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

Let me start by saying that I am very confused that there is no answer for this question on stackoverflow - at least i didn't find one. So I guess my problem has to quite specific although I don't get why. This question was already asked similarly over 1 year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087137/java-swing-metal-jbutton-focus-border-size)

The question has not been answered and because it is so old I will ask it again. I don't have any metal design going on as in the original question, all I'm doing is creating a simple button inside of a panel (I'm using eclipse to design the application) but the focus border only wraps around the text and does not scale with the size of the button but only with the size of the font.

Here is my whole design code (its not much since I just started)

```
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
    MainPanel.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
    MainPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    MainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 995, 465);
    contentPane.add(MainPanel);
    MainPanel.setLayout(null);

    JButton StartButton = new JButton("Launch Oasis");
    StartButton.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    StartButton.setBackground(new Color(169, 169, 169));
    StartButton.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 128));
    StartButton.setBounds(397, 197, 200, 50);
    StartButton.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    MainPanel.add(StartButton);
```

[image: This is the button I'm talking about]

I want to stress the same thing the original author did, I want the focus border to be painted so `jButton.setFocusPainted(false);` wouldn't solve my problem.
Is there any obvious reason for the focus border no scaling with the size of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer contains my research in response to camickr's provided sources.

Change the Look and Feel of your application to the Windows Look and Feel by adding the following to your main method **before** creating the JFrame. For it to work you'll need to `import javax.swing.UIManager;`:

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

This will give you a focus border next to the button border wrapping around the whole button. Note that this method can throw a bunch of Exceptions `(ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException)`. For further information on this topic, you can visit the [Modifying the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) section of the swing tutorial.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212945/discussion-on-answer-by-user1337-java-swing-focus-border-too-small).

Comment: This posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61576461/131872 contains the normal interaction. 1) a question is asked 2) the answer highlights the problem, suggests a possible solution and provides a link to a tutorial for more information 3) the answer is accepted and the OP provided a brief summary how they used the information provided to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a few observations about the code:

1. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn Java naming conventions and follow them. The forum is highlighting your variables like they are class names, making it difficult to read your code.
2. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Don't use setBounds(). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

> Is there any obvious reason for the focus border no scaling with the size of the button?

Is there any obvious reason it should scale with the size of the button?

The focus border is designed to be a visual cue when the button has focus.

Each LAF can choose how this should be done.

This LAF choose to have the focus border around the text/icon.

I would suggest if it scaled to the size of the button then you wouldn't be able to see it because it would blend in with the border.

If you don't like the fact that the left/right margins are bigger than the top/bottom margins then you can use:

```
button.setMargins( new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5) );
```

Again. the designers of the LAF like the horizontal margins to be bigger.
Edit:

> Is there any way to give this jButton a windows feeling

Use the Windows LAF.

There is a section in the Swing tutorial on `"Modifying the Look and Feel"`. You have already been given a link to the Swing tutorial. You will find the section in the Table of Contents, by clicking on the "Trail" link found at the top of the page of each section in the tutorial.

Comment: I know the naming convenitons, belief me, it's a bad VB.NET habit to do this for GUIs. The whole syntax is capitalized there. I intentionally chose an absolute layout because I don't want to be bound to a layout. Windows buttons render the focus border around the outside of the button so I expected it to work the same. My bad. Is there any way to give this jButton a windows feeling and set the focus border bounds? By the way, .NET renders the focus border and the button border next to each other and it looks just fine.

Comment: *I know the naming convenitons,* - then use them if you want people to take the time to look at your code. *I don't want to be bound to a layout.* - That is what people new to Swing think because that is all that is available in other languages. Layout managers exist to make your life easier. Take the time to learn them and your code will be easier to write and maintain, especially when you start using different LAF like you want to do with this question. *Is there any way to give this jButton a windows feeling* - see edit.