# GridBagLayout does not display a component

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I wrote a component to display a circular progressbar. When I put it in `BorderLayout` everything looks fine.

[image]

But it can't be seen when a `GridBagLayout` is set.

[image]

```
    p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    p.add(north(), gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(west(), gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(bar, gbc);
```

I have no idea whether it is the problem of setting the `GridBagConstraints` or other reasons.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). BTW 1) from the look of the truncated labels, it appears the code is guessing the size of the frame. Instead `pack()` it. 2) GBL does not play well when there is too little space for a component. It generally won't display it at all. So, again, `pack()` the top level container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it can't be seen when a GridBagLayout is set.

Probably because you didn't override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your component so the preferred size will be (0, 0).

The GridBagLayout will attempt to display the component at its preferred size.

I would guess you would need to use the `fill` constraint when adding the component so it can be automatically resized to fill the space available in the cell. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

> When I put it in BorderLayout everything looks fine.

When added to the CENTER of a BorderLayout the component will be resized to fill the space available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion about using `fill()`. That's the key of how I solve the problem. It can be seen though it looked like it was covered by the panel on the left. So I also set both `weightx` and `weighty` to extreme(1.0),  to prevent the components from clumping together in the centre,  which made it look as what I want.